# What impact does the choice of estimated class enrollment have in Piazza?

Tags: piazza

When creating a new class in Piazza, it asks for the estimated class enrollment. What impact does the choice of estimated class enrollment have? I.e. what the difference is between choosing 10, 100 or 1000?

https://piazza.com/instructors/mit :

[image]